# How to forward gpg-agent from host to docker container and reuse cached passphrase?

Tags: security, docker, gpg, gpg-agent

Information:

```
GPG version: 2.2.23
Docker version 20.10.5
```

I am playing around with GPG on my laptop and trying to reuse it inside docker container.

The docker container is simply a PHP-FPM alpine image. I have simple PHP CLI tool which encrypt/decrypts data with GPG. I exported the GPG from host and imported it inside container. The problem though, I always need to provide passphrase for PHP to decrypt the data. I would like to avoid passphrase in container for sake of security.

Further I discovered the  `gpg-agent` with `gpg-preset-passphrase` and preconfigured it inside the container, but later on found that this isn't optimal, because once I restart the container or destroy it, I will need to start `gpg-agent` and set passphrase again.

So, I was wondering, is there a way to pass `gpg-agent` with cached passphrase inside docker and so docker would reuse it to encrypt/decrypt the data?

I know there is possibility to reuse ssh-agent inside docker, but couldn't really find a way to do the same for GPG.

Or maybe there is a better/secure way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the resolution was very simple.

### GPG

First of all, you need to start `gpg-agent`:

```
gpg-agent --verbose --daemon --log-file /tmp/gpg-agent.log --allow-preset-passphrase --default-cache-ttl=31536000
```

This will start gpg-agent in background. You can verify that it is running:

```
ps aux | grep gpg
```

Now you need to use `gpg-preset-passphrase` to preset passphrase for the private key. `gpg-preset-passphrase` is not located in the `/usr/local/bin`, so you need to find it:

```
sudo find / -name gpg-preset-passphrase
```

In my case it was `/usr/local/Cellar/gnupg/2.3.1_1/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase`, so now run the following command to find out private KEYID:

```
gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye
```

Sample output:

```
S KEYINFO 4B86D9FBE0D9617C6EB4B42015C9B2AC8XXXXXXX D - - - P - - -
S KEYINFO 8960D3408E09A1A111AA862DBFB1B16CFXXXXXXX D - - - P - - -
OK
```

In my case it is two keys, choose one of the KEY IDs.

```
echo "your-secret-passphrase" | /your/path/to/gpg-preset-passphrase --verbose --preset 4B86D9FBE0D9617C6EB4B42015C9B2AC8XXXXXXX
```

Replace `your-secret-passphrase` with your password, `/your/path/to/` with your path and `4B86D9FBE0D9617C6EB4B42015C9B2AC8XXXXXXX` with your own KEYID.

Now run the following command again to verify that passphrase was set successfully:

```
gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye
```

If you see "1" near the KEYID you've chosen, it means passphrase set successfully.

Let's verify by doing encrypt and decrypt:

```
echo "hello" | gpg --armor --encrypt --recipient email@example.com | gpg --decrypt
```

Replace `email@example.com` with your email.

### GPG Agent Forwarding via SSH

Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host gpgtunnel
    User user
    HostName server-ip
    Port 22
    RemoteForward /root/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent /home/user/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

`RemoteForward` has the following signature: `<remote path> <local path>`. You can find location of local path by running:

```
gpgconf --list-dir agent-extra-socket
```

ssh to you server and find remote path by running:

```
gpgconf --list-dir agent-socket
```

> Some note about `S.gpg-agent` vs `S.gpg-agent.extra`. `S.gpg-agent` allows to do export of the private key and other manipulation with keys, where is `S.gpg-agent.extra` is a very limit version which allows only encrypt/decrypt operation.

Now you need to export public key to remote sever, you can use the following command:

```
gpg --export email@example.com | ssh -p 22 user@remote-server gpg --import
```

Replace `email@example.com` with your GPG email.

Ensure you have imported public key successfully:

```
ssh -p 22 user@remote-server gpg -k
```

#### Testing

Now try to run `ssh gpgtunnel` and do encrypt/decrypt on the server. Now server should be able to reuse your local gpg-agent socket.

```
echo "hello" | gpg --armor --encrypt --recipient gpg.for.testing.in.docker@example.com | gpg --decrypt
```

If for some reason this doesn't work, you may run the following SSH command from your local computer:

```
ssh -fNT gpgtunnel
```

This will put SSH to background (-f flag). Now `ssh gpgtunnel` normally and retry encrypt/decrypt command from above again.

#### Resources

- https://wiki.gnupg.org/AgentForwarding
- https://habd.as/post/moving-gpg-keys-privately/